# How get child elements with java lambda to put in a Map<Long, List<Long>>?

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda

I have one Object with this structure:

```
@JsonProperty("id")
private Long codigoCategoria;

@JsonProperty("parentId")
private Long codigoCategoriaPai;

@JsonProperty("name")
private String nomeCategoria;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
private ComissaoPadraoEntity comissao;

@JsonProperty("categories")
private List<CategoriaDTO> subCategorias;
```

How can you see, it has a list of his own type, i need map this categories with a Map `<Long,List<Long>>`. Where the key is codigoCategoria, and the value must be a List of Long with codigoCategoria inside the subCategorias.

This is the payload structure:

```
  {
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": "1813",
      "parentId": null,
      "name": "Malas e Mochilas",
      "items": 12,
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": "1827",
          "parentId": "1813",
          "name": "Conjuntos de Malas",
          "items": 0,
          "categories": [

          ],
          "attributes": null
        },
        {
          "id": "1830",
          "parentId": "1813",
          "name": "Mochilas",
          "items": 4,
          "categories": [
            {
              "id": "1831",
              "parentId": "1830",
              "name": "Mochila Esportiva",
              "items": 0,
              "categories": [

              ],
```

At so far i have been tried on many different ways, this is the code i have done, but even doesn't compile:

```
private Map<Long, List<Long>> mapATreeofCategories() {
        List<CategoriaDTO> categories = getAll();
        Map<Long, List<Long>> treeCategories = categories.forEach(categoriaDTO -> {
            categories.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(categoriaDTO.getCodigoCategoria(),
                            categoriaDTO.getSubCategorias().forEach(categoriaDTO1 -> categoriaDTO1.getCodigoCategoria())));
        });
        return treeCategories;
    }
```

Thanks for any help guys.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: I get this error: Collectors.toMap cannot be aplied with (long, void). I have tried to map the properties, flat map but not work too.

Comment: Feel free to [edit] your question with the error message. The problem is that `forEach()` returns `void` so it cannot be used in the way you are attempting to use it. I am unfamiliar with the Stream API so cannot help much further.

Comment: `Map<Long, List<Long>> treeCategories = categories.forEach...`
do you know forEach is a Consumer and has void type.

Comment: @GustavoSimõesdeMoraes you probably just want `categories.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(c -> c.getCodigoCategoria(),
                 v ->  v.getSubCategorias()
                        .stream()
                        .map(e -> e.getCodigoCategoria()).collect(Collectors.toList())
                 );` ? if not then you need to edit your post to clarify exactly what you're after.

Comment: @Aominè, Thanks a lot. Sorry for delay I was testing and this is exacly what i need. If is not asked to much can you indicate some site or books about lambda, i m new using the new recourses of java 8. Sorry for my english too kkk.

Answer (score 1):

The `forEach` method has a `void` return type so cannot be used as the return value in the `valueMapper` function.

instead, it seems like you want to extract the `CodigoCategoria` from the `subCategories` collection, in which case you need to do it as follows:

```
categories.stream() 
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k.getCodigoCategoria(), 
                      v -> v.getSubCategorias().stream() 
                             .map(e -> e.getCodigoCategoria())
                             .collect(Collectors.toList()) 
          );
```

Comment: i understand. i have just one question can i make this method recursive with lambda, for examplo, with i have a structure with three levels or more, let s say i have one object CategoriaDTO and has a list and inside this list i have many CategoriaDTO but in that lis can have a list to. If i have just two levels works fine but with a have more it not included in the list.

Comment: @GustavoSimõesdeMoraes you can't nest anything inside `Long` so maximum depth for your structure (`Map <Long,List<Long>>`) is two levels (root and sub-root) only

Comment: @Nikolay Shevchenko but even make this method recursive ? I did something similar in another method, but not using lambda with this level only with forEach. I m trying to collect the values,  calling this method recursive but dont work :(